# Eclipse Milo doesn't reconnect to server after lost connection - subscriptions

Tags: java, kotlin, opc-ua, milo

I am working on subscriptions with Milo and I am trying to make re-connection after connection to server is lost. I subscribe a few thousands of nodes. I added custom `SubscriptionListener` and after I break a network I receive calls to `onPublishFailure()` in my `SubscriptionListener` where I invoke `subscriptionManager.clearSubscriptions()` and then I resubscribe the same nodes but nothing happens after that.

What's correct approach to handle a lost connection to server for subscriptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct approach is mostly to do nothing - all of the details of reconnecting are handled automatically.

The only case you need to handle is when the subscriptions were unable to be transferred after a new session was created. Implement `SubscriptionListener#onSubscriptionTransferFailed` to re-create any subscription this callback indicates has failed to transfer.

There's not really any other scenario where you should be manually clearing and re-creating your subscriptions. The `onPublishFailure()` callback is largely informational and does not require action.

Comment: I tried as you said but I am constantly receiving  `TRACE o.e.m.o.s.c.t.tcp.OpcTcpTransport - Write succeeded for request=ReadRequest, requestHandle=98 DEBUG o.e.m.o.stack.client.UaStackClient - sendRequest() failed, request=ReadRequest, requestHandle=77
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: UaException: status=Bad_Timeout, message=requestId=77 timed out after 5000ms` after I resume network connection

Comment: That doesn't mean anything on its own other than the server didn't respond to a ReadRequest within the configured 5000ms timeout.

Comment: My client's config settings are:             `OpcUaClientConfig.builder().setApplicationUri("urn:eclipse:milo:examples:client")
            .setCertificate(loader.getClientCertificate())
            .setKeyPair(loader.getClientKeyPair())
            .setEndpoint(endpoint)
            .setIdentityProvider(AnonymousProvider())
            .setRequestTimeout(Unsigned.uint(20_000))
            .setKeepAliveFailuresAllowed(UInteger.MAX)
            .setKeepAliveInterval(Unsigned.uint(10_000))
            .build()`

Comment: Why are you effectively disabling the keep alive by setting the failures to Integer.MAX? You're preventing the client from detecting a connection loss from the server in many scenarios.

Comment: regarding my network disconnections, server is behind vpn so I just close connection with vpn and then I resume it

Comment: Remove your configuration that changes the keep alive settings and you should see the client detect the server is no longer responding and begin reconnecting.

Comment: I tried from my code and from `SubscriptionExample`. From my code still as above only a new log appeared `o.e.milo.opcua.sdk.client.SessionFsm - [2] Keep Alive failureCount=2 exceeds failuresAllowed=1`. For SubscriptionExample after I connected my network cable I constantly receive `TRACE o.e.m.o.s.c.t.tcp.OpcTcpTransport - Write succeeded for request=ReadRequest, requestHandle=53` and that's all.

Comment: for `SubscriptionExample` I use `milo.digitalpetri.com` server

Comment: SubscriptionExample doesn't implement recovery, so I'm not sure what you expect. Try this modified version: https://gist.github.com/kevinherron/f2dfc6aaf62360de35dd595fc5930654 - it recovers and starts printing subscription values after it reconnects.

Comment: I just set `setKeepAliveFailuresAllowed(UInteger.MAX)` for SubscriptionExample and it works as expected. So I don't understand why it should be default?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the way you're simulating a disconnect. The reason the keep alive failures are important is that there are failure modes, like a VPN disconnecting, where the OS doesn't necessarily know that the TCP connection is bad. The default TCP layer keep alive is something like 2 hours on most OS. So certain kinds of failure can take a long time before we finally get notified. The application layer keep alive failures in Milo detect these faster. Other more normal failures will be reported to us as Exceptions and handled immediately.

Comment: Unfortunately no progress while I simulate disconnect with VPN. The exception is the same CompletionException from org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.transport.AbstractTransport.lambda$scheduleRequestTimeout$7(AbstractTransport.java:143)

Comment: Did you revert back to the default keep alive settings?

Comment: Yes, I reverted it to default. After ~15 minutes I received `java.io.IOException: Connection timed out` and there was client/channel restart and works now. 15 minutes it's  seems to be some default Netty timeout but I cannot find information about this.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best way to relay on that timeout. Maybe you know some better way to handle this?

Comment: The keep alive mechanism is supposed to be the workaround for not relying on however long it takes the network layer to figure out the connection is longer good. I have not observed this mechanism failing. I'm going to test the modified subscription example against a server over VPN in a couple minutes to verify.

Comment: The modified SubscriptionExample I linked to reconnects successfully after disconnecting VPN, waiting a bit, then reconnecting. If you want further help troubleshooting this you should probably move the conversation to the Milo mailing list and provide logs and code samples.